# jQuery form Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins, submit

I am trying to upload and submit through AJAX a form and I found jQuery.form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/, here is my code :

```
     $("#submitSlide").click(function(){

         var options = { 
            success:    function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
            },
            error : function( jqXHR , textStatus , errorThrown ){
               console.log( ' broked ' , jqXHR , textStatus , errorThrown );
           } ,
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'http://www.slideshare.net/api/1/upload_slideshow'
        };

        $('#ssuploadform').ajaxSubmit(options);


         return false;
     });
```

But I am getting an error  like this :

```
    >>[jquery.form] Server abort: Error: Permission denied to access property 'document' (Error)
    >>[jquery.form] cannot access response document: Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
    >>[jquery.form] aborting upload... aborted
```

DO you have any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks, I appreciate any help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

You cannot make a cross-origin XHR. See [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript) for ideas.